# AllureRunListener deprecated in allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor 1.6.2

Tags: java, selenium, jvm, cucumber, allure

The AllureRunListener constructor is deprecated in allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor 1.6.2 and I want to replace it. There is a link pointing to https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor in the AllureRunListener class, but I can't figure out from the example how to set up the listener in the new version as it was before. This is how I the code looks like where AllureRunListener() is called:

```
private static void runTest(final String allureResultsDirectory) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    final JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
    runner.addListener(new AllureRunListener());
    runner.run(getTestClass());
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered switching to Allure 2.0 adapter for Junit / Cucumber JVM?

- https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_junit_4
- https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_cucumber_jvm